# Is there a way to identify or return characters contributing to difference between 2 words in edit distance in python?

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, nlp, edit-distance

I am looking find patterns in spelling mistakes. I am able to use edit distance to see how similar 2 words(correct word and candidate word) are. However, I am also interested to know which characters are contributing in creating the difference between the 2 words.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library and method that you are using. For example, in [this library](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein#documentation) you can use [`editops`](https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-editops) function to find all edit operations in addition to the Levenstein distance of two strings:

```
editops('spam', 'park')
# [('delete', 0, 0), ('insert', 3, 2), ('replace', 3, 3)]
```